Newton's third law opposing first law itself giving extra force?
If an object strikes a wall with a force $F$ and come back with same velocity in straight line only, at the moment of collision the object give force $F$ and experiences a reaction $F$, so the reaction $F$ will be used to stop the motion of the object. It should fell down, but it comes back with same velocity and opposite direction backwards (straight line). But to make it come back with same velocity in opposite direction, the forward motion should be stopped first, then, again, $F$ is required to make it accelerate backwards, but the wall can give only $F$. Though, $F$ is used to stop the motion, so who gives force to move back? If $F$ is used to move back, then who stops forward motion in straight line $180^\circ$ backwards?
From where the extra force come? If we want to stop an object moving in straight line in same line and move back, we need to first stop forward motion; then it will stop. Then, again, force is required to move back.

There is no extra force here.

First you should change statements like, it come back with same velocity in opposite direction, to it come back with same speed (magnitude of velocity)  in opposite direction.
When the object strikes the wall, the wall applies a force in a direction opposite to the direction of motion of the object and continues to apply a force in that direction until the object, now travelling in the opposite direction, loses contact with the wall.
Thus the speed of the object decreases, goes to zero and then increses again with the direction of the force applied by the wall on the object always being the same.

I think your misconception lies in assuming that the force experienced by the object is "only strong enough" to stop the object. What you did is fixing the force experienced by the object beforehand to an arbitrary magnitude, which is of course an incorrect approach.
When solving such an elastic collision problem, the outcome may be calculated through conservation of momentum and energy. Given initial momenta, these two conservation laws already determine the trajectory of the object. One finds that the object will bounce off the wall after impact and will travel back whence it came with the same speed it initially approached.
But then the momenta as function of time are known. And the forces, which are their derivatives, are determined thereby as well. So, the force acting on the object in this setting is merely a result of how the momentum of the object changes, not vice versa! In other words, you cannot prescribe the force beforehand and try to determine the outcome, for this may violate conservation of momentum and energy.
In conclusion, your assumption that the force is only "strong enough" to stop the object is wrong, as the forces must in principle be "strong enough" to stop AND reverse the course of the object simply by conservation of momentum and energy.
